# How to retain image file in django

Tags: python, django

I have a newclaim form which allows user to upload a picture and editclaims which allows users to retain or add new pictures which will overwrite the old one.

The current problem I faced is whenever I try to edit without making any changes, the picture will become an empty field so I have to resubmit the picture again.

How do I solve this?
**This is my views.py**

```
# Submit a new Claim
def newclaim(request):
  
  context = initialize_context(request)
  user = context['user']
  if request.method == 'POST':
   
      receipt = request.FILES['receipt_field']
     
      ins = SaveClaimForm(receipt=receipt)
      ins.save()
      print("The Data has been written")

  return render(request, 'Login/newclaim.html/', {'user':user})

    # Edit a claim
    def editclaims(request,id):
        context = initialize_context(request)
        user = context['user']
    
        # get original object     
        claims = SaveClaimForm.objects.get(id=id)
    
        if request.method == 'POST':
    
            # update original object

          receipt = request.FILES['receipt_field']
         
            # save it with original `ID`
            claims.save()
          
        return render(request, "Login/editclaims.html", {'claims':claims, 'user':user})
```

**This is my editclaims.html**

```
 <form method="POST" action="/editclaims/{{claims.id}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div>
                    <input id="receipt" name="receipt" type="file" value="receipt"> 
                    <label for="receipt"> {{ claims.receipt }} </label> 
                </div>
 </form>
```

**This is my newclaim.html**

```
<form action="/newclaim/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <div>
                <input id="receipt" type="file" name="receipt_field" style="display: none; visibility: none;">
      </div>
</form>
```

**This is my SaveClaimForm models**

```
class SaveClaimForm(models.Model):
    receipt = models.FileField(upload_to='receipts/%Y/%m/%D', validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['jpg','png'])])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming here that you've removed a lot of code before posting this question, as currently the form is only for submitting the file, which means when editing a `SaveClaimForm` instance (very confusingly named, as it's not a Form in the Django sense of the word) you would only be saving the form, and therefore there would be no point if `receipt` wasn't a required field.

You simply need to check that the file field has been filled in.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    # update original object
    receipt_file = request.FILES.get('receipt_field')

    # Do the other things to save the SaveClaimForm object

    if receipt_file:
        claims.receipt = receipt_file
    claims.save()
return render('blah')
```

Comment: are you suggesting to make receipt a required field?

Comment: Not if you don't want it to be changed

Comment: Whenever I edit another field, somehow the picture is gone

Comment: You're code posted above shows no other fields; it's hard for me to diagnose without knowing what you're trying to do. Please can you post the full code?